# tkinter Button does not open new window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, window

I’m experiencing problems with tkinter.
I have code that is meant to open a new window on button press, but the window does not open.

Here’s my code:

**Main Module**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding: latin-1
import tkinter
import ce

#window config
window = tkinter.Tk()                   #create window
window.title("BBDOassist")              #set title
window.geometry("750x500")              #set size

…

#   buttons
button_ce = tkinter.Button(window, text="CE Evaluation", command="ce.run()")
button_ce.pack()


window.mainloop()                       #draw the window and start
```

**’CE’ Module**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding: latin-1
import tkinter

…

def run():
  #window config
    window = tkinter.Tk()                                   #create window
    window.title("BBDOassist - CE Evaluation")              #set title
    window.geometry("750x500")                              #set size

…

    window.mainloop()                                    #draw the window and start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems

First, you must give the `command` attribute a reference to a function. You are passing it a string. A string is useless. You need to change your button definition to this:

```
button_ce = tkinter.Button(window, text="CE Evaluation", command=ce.run)
```

Second, if you want to create additional windows then you need to create instances of `Toplevel` rather than `Tk`. A tkinter program needs exactly one instance of `Tk`, and you need to call `mainloop` exactly once.

Change `run` to look like this (and remove the call to `mainloop` inside `run`):

```
def run():
    #window config
    window = tkinter.Toplevel()
    ...
```